# Por que no imprime mas de una variable dentro de la ruleta?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql-server

En este archivo index del repositorio mio, dejo este proyecto lo quiero conectar a una base de datos pero el problema   es que no logro, hacer que se impriman mas de una variable y la misma se muestre con su linea de division.

este es el repositorio de la ruleta c*mpleta

```
https://github.com/jvczxc/rullete
```

Ahora necesito que imprima o echo mas de una variable en el mismo dejo la consulta SQL y una capture de la ruletica.

[image: espada larga es lo que sale y necesito que salgan mas items]

los items que deberian imprimirse son:

```
Espada Larga
Posima Premio
Premio2
Premio3
```

El script en html es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head runat='server'>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <title>La ruleta de la muerte</title>
    <script src='js/Winwheel.min.js'></script>

<script src='./js/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
<script src='./js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
    <script src='./js/sweetalert.min.js'></script>
    <link href='./css/sweetalert.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    
<meta property='og:url'               content='./' />
<meta property='og:type'               content='article' />
<meta property='og:title'              content='La ruleta (Rifa cosas)' />
<meta property='og:description'        content='Con esta ruleta online puedes rifar lo que gustes, solo llena la lista y genera tu ruleta' />

</head>
<body>
<center>
   <form id='form1' runat='server'>

    <div>
        <style>
         #canvasContainer {
            background-image: url(img/Muerte.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;  
            background-position: center;   
            width: 700px;                  
            height: 700px;
            cursor:pointer;
        
        }

        </style>

        <div class='container-fluid'>

            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-3 text-center'>  
                   <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div style='display:none;' class='card bg-warning'>
  <div class='card-body'>
  
                  <h4 class='card-title'>Lista de elementos:</h4>  
                    
<textarea id='ListaElementos' style='display:none;' class='form-control' rows='13'>
<?php
// Crear Tabla de Premios por ItemID, Restado Y o Sumado de AP por Ruleta
$premios=mssql_query('
SELECT a.ItemName, b.ItemID
FROM  PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items a
INNER JOIN PS_GameLog.dbo.ruleta b
on b.ItemID = a.ItemID'); 
WHILE ($Items  = mssql_fetch_array ($premios)){
$print = $Items['0']." ";
echo $print; 
echo "</textarea>";
}
?>
<br />
                    <input type='button' onclick='leerElementos()' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block' value='Generar Ruleta'/><br />
      </div></div>
      
                </div>
                <div class='col-7 text-center'>
                <br/>
                     <input id='bigButton' style='display:none;' class='btn-block btn-lg btn btn-success ' onclick='objRuleta.startAnimation(); this.disabled=true;' value='Girar' type='button'/>
                     <div id='canvasContainer' onclick='objRuleta.startAnimation();bigButton.disabled = true;'>
     <canvas id='Ruleta' width='700' height='690'></canvas> 
        
            </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-2'>
                                    <br/>
                    <script async src='./js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>
<!-- anuncio160_600 -->
<ins class='adsbygoogle'
     style='display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px'
     data-ad-client='ca-pub-4331617637495482'
     data-ad-slot='3603100456'></ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

                </div>
            </div>
      

            </div>

     <script>
         var objRuleta;
         var winningSegment;
         var distnaciaX = 150;
         var distnaciaY = 50;
         var ctx ;
         function Mensaje() {
             winningSegment = objRuleta.getIndicatedSegment();
             SonidoFinal();
             swal({
                title: 'ยก '+winningSegment.text+' !',
               
                 imageUrl: 'img/Muerte.png',
                 confirmButtonColor: '#e74c3c',
                 confirmButtonText: 'Ok,Reiniciar',
                 cancelButtonText: 'Quitar elemento',
                 closeOnConfirm: true,
                 closeOnCancel: true
             },
      function (isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
             
          } else {

              $('#ListaElementos').val($('#ListaElementos').val().replace(winningSegment.text,''));
              leerElementos();
              
          }
          objRuleta.stopAnimation(false);
          objRuleta.rotationAngle = 0;
          objRuleta.draw();
          DibujarTriangulo();
          bigButton.disabled = false;
      });

      }

         function DibujarTriangulo() {
             distnaciaX = 150;
             distnaciaY = 1;
             ctx = objRuleta.ctx;
             ctx.strokeStyle = 'navy';
             ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
             ctx.lineWidth = 2;
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.moveTo(distnaciaX + 170, distnaciaY + 5);
             ctx.lineTo(distnaciaX + 230, distnaciaY + 5);
             ctx.lineTo(distnaciaX + 200, distnaciaY + 40);
             ctx.lineTo(distnaciaX + 171, distnaciaY + 5);
             ctx.stroke();
             ctx.fill();
         }

         function DibujarRuleta(ArregloElementos) {
             
               objRuleta = new Winwheel({
                 'canvasId': 'Ruleta',
                 'numSegments': ArregloElementos.length,
                 'outerRadius': 330,
                 'innerRadius': 80,
                 'segments':ArregloElementos,
                 'animation':
                 {
                     'type': 'spinToStop',
                     'duration':4,
                     'spins': 15,
                     'callbackFinished': 'Mensaje()',
                     'callbackAfter': 'DibujarTriangulo()' 
                     
                 }, 
                
             });
    
               DibujarTriangulo();
      }
        function leerElementos() {
                  txtListaElementos=$('#ListaElementos').val().trim();
                  var Elementos = txtListaElementos.split('$$');
                  var ElementosRuleta= [];
              Elementos.forEach(function (Elemento) {
                      if(Elemento){
                      ElementosRuleta.push({ 'fillStyle': '#' + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16), 'text': Elemento });
                  }
                  });
                  DibujarRuleta(ElementosRuleta);
         } 
         leerElementos();
          var audio = new Audio('alarma.mp3');  // Create audio object and load desired file.
        function SonidoFinal()
            {
                audio.pause();
                audio.currentTime = 0;
                audio.play();
            }
 
</script>
    </div>
    </form>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-74824848-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>


</center>
</body>
```

La consulta de SQL es:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ruleta] (
[RowID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[ItemID] int NULL ,
[Tipo] varchar(6) NULL 
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ruleta] ([RowID], [ItemID], [Tipo]) VALUES (N'1', N'1001', null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ruleta] ([RowID], [ItemID], [Tipo]) VALUES (N'2', N'1002', null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ruleta] ([RowID], [ItemID], [Tipo]) VALUES (N'3', N'100001', null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ruleta] ([RowID], [ItemID], [Tipo]) VALUES (N'4', N'25005', null)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items] (
[RowID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[ItemID] int NULL ,
[ItemName] varchar(6) NULL 
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ruleta] ([RowID], [ItemID], [Tipo]) VALUES (N'1', N'1001', 'Espada Larga')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ruleta] ([RowID], [ItemID], [Tipo]) VALUES (N'2', N'1002', 'Posima Premio')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ruleta] ([RowID], [ItemID], [Tipo]) VALUES (N'3', N'100001', 'Premio2')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ruleta] ([RowID], [ItemID], [Tipo]) VALUES (N'4', N'25005', 'Premio3')
```

Comment: no te entendi nada y al parecer debo borra la respuesta o colocar mi respuesta ya que lo que tuve que colocar es una siimple coma (,) al hacer esto $print = $Items['0'].",";
 en la linea 182 ref (var Elementos = txtListaElementos.split(',');)

Answer (score 1):

la respuesta es una simple coma (,) en el Index y eliminar el archivo premios.php
en los comentarios di la respuesta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head runat='server'>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <title>La ruleta de la muerte</title>
    <script src='js/Winwheel.min.js'></script>

<script src='./js/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
<script src='./js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
    <script src='./js/sweetalert.min.js'></script>
    <link href='./css/sweetalert.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    
<meta property='og:url'               content='./' />
<meta property='og:type'               content='article' />
<meta property='og:title'              content='La ruleta (Rifa cosas)' />
<meta property='og:description'        content='Con esta ruleta online puedes rifar lo que gustes, solo llena la lista y genera tu ruleta' />

</head>
<body>
<center>
                    <h5> Para Usar Debes Tener 500 APs en tu cuenta: AP Actual <font color='green'>50 APs En Usuario: JVCZXC</font></h5>
    <form id='form1' runat='server'>

    <div>
        <style>
         #canvasContainer {
            background-image: url(img/Muerte.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;  
            background-position: center;   
            width: 700px;                  
            height: 700px;
            cursor:pointer;
        
        }

        </style>

        <div class='container-fluid'>

            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-3 text-center'>  
                   <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div style='display:none;' class='card bg-warning'>
  <div class='card-body'>
  
                  <h4 class='card-title'>Lista de elementos:</h4>  
                    
<textarea id='ListaElementos' style='display:none;' class='form-control' rows='13'>
<?php
include_once"../../includes/mssql_conex.php";
$premios=mssql_query('
SELECT a.ItemName, b.ItemID
FROM  PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items a
INNER JOIN PS_GameLog.dbo.ruleta b
on b.ItemID = a.ItemID'); 
WHILE ($Items  = mssql_fetch_array ($premios)){
$print = $Items['0'].",";
echo $print; 
// echo "";
}

?>
</textarea>
<br />
                    <input type='button' onclick='leerElementos()' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block' value='Generar Ruleta'/><br />
      </div></div>
      
                </div>
                <div class='col-7 text-center'>
                <br/>
                     <input id='bigButton' style='display:none;' class='btn-block btn-lg btn btn-success ' onclick='objRuleta.startAnimation(); this.disabled=true;' value='Girar' type='button'/>
                     <div id='canvasContainer' onclick='objRuleta.startAnimation();bigButton.disabled = true;'>
     <canvas id='Ruleta' width='700' height='690'></canvas> 
        
            </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-2'>
                                    <br/>
                    <script async src='./js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>
<!-- anuncio160_600 -->
<ins class='adsbygoogle'
     style='display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px'
     data-ad-client='ca-pub-4331617637495482'
     data-ad-slot='3603100456'></ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

                </div>
            </div>
      

            </div>

     <script>
         var objRuleta;
         var winningSegment;
         var distnaciaX = 150;
         var distnaciaY = 50;
         var ctx ;
         function Mensaje() {
             winningSegment = objRuleta.getIndicatedSegment();
             SonidoFinal();
             swal({
                title: 'ยก '+winningSegment.text+' !',
               
                 imageUrl: 'img/Muerte.png',
                 confirmButtonColor: '#e74c3c',
                 confirmButtonText: 'Ok,Reiniciar',
                 cancelButtonText: 'Quitar elemento',
                 closeOnConfirm: true,
                 closeOnCancel: true
             },
      function (isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
             
          } else {

              $('#ListaElementos').val($('#ListaElementos').val().replace(winningSegment.text,''));
              leerElementos();
              
          }
          objRuleta.stopAnimation(false);
          objRuleta.rotationAngle = 0;
          objRuleta.draw();
          DibujarTriangulo();
          bigButton.disabled = false;
      });

      }

         function DibujarTriangulo() {
             distnaciaX = 150;
             distnaciaY = 1;
             ctx = objRuleta.ctx;
             ctx.strokeStyle = 'navy';
             ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
             ctx.lineWidth = 2;
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.moveTo(distnaciaX + 170, distnaciaY + 5);
             ctx.lineTo(distnaciaX + 230, distnaciaY + 5);
             ctx.lineTo(distnaciaX + 200, distnaciaY + 40);
             ctx.lineTo(distnaciaX + 171, distnaciaY + 5);
             ctx.stroke();
             ctx.fill();
         }

         function DibujarRuleta(ArregloElementos) {
             
               objRuleta = new Winwheel({
                 'canvasId': 'Ruleta',
                 'numSegments': ArregloElementos.length,
                 'outerRadius': 330,
                 'innerRadius': 80,
                 'segments':ArregloElementos,
                 'animation':
                 {
                     'type': 'spinToStop',
                     'duration':4,
                     'spins': 15,
                     'callbackFinished': 'Mensaje()',
                     'callbackAfter': 'DibujarTriangulo()' 
                     
                 }, 
                
             });
    
               DibujarTriangulo();
      }
        function leerElementos() {
                  txtListaElementos=$('#ListaElementos').val().trim();
                  var Elementos = txtListaElementos.split(',');
                  var ElementosRuleta= [];
              Elementos.forEach(function (Elemento) {
                      if(Elemento){
                      ElementosRuleta.push({ 'fillStyle': '#' + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16), 'text': Elemento });
                  }
                  });
                  DibujarRuleta(ElementosRuleta);
         } 
         leerElementos();
          var audio = new Audio('alarma.mp3');  // Create audio object and load desired file.
        function SonidoFinal()
            {
                audio.pause();
                audio.currentTime = 0;
                audio.play();
            }
 
</script>
    </div>
    </form>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-74824848-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>


<input type='text' name='usuario' placeholder='Ingrese su usuario'><br/>
<input type='text' name='pw' placeholder='Ingrese su Pass'>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```